# Using a highstock chart with stacked series

Tags: charts, highcharts

I currently have a highcharts stacked column chart that looks like this:

[image]

And I have so much data to put in that chart that it just would look ugly and wouldn't fit with the width:

[image]

Notice that I have 4 colours in each column in the two screenshots

So I wanted to use a highstock chart where the user is able to zoom in and out of data such as: https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/column

Is there a way, however, that I can use it while maintaining the stacking?

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4x4ued5/) that contains a small sample data of my stacked chart and here's its code:

```
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', 
    {
  "chart": {
    "type": "column"
  },
  "title": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": [
      "Start Term 1",
      "Start Term 2",
      "29-Sep",
      "Start Term 3",
      "03-Oct",
      "05-Oct",
      "Start Term 4",
      "12-Oct",
      "20-Oct",
      "23-Oct",
      "30-Oct",
      "17-Nov",
      "21-Nov"
    ],
    "labels": {
      "style": {
        "font-size": "12px"
      },
      "useHTML": true
    }
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Time (hh:mm)"
    },
    "tickInterval": 600,
    "labels": {},
    "gridLineWidth": 0,
    "plotLines": [
      {
        "value": 0,
        "width": 1,
        "color": "#000",
        "zIndex": 4
      }
    ],
    "tickmarkPlacement": "on"
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "column": {
      "stacking": "normal",
      "events": {}
    }
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "shared": true,
    "crosshairs": true
  },
  "legend": {
    "align": "right",
    "verticalAlign": "top",
    "itemStyle": {
      "display": "none"
    },
    "title": {
      "text": "Click a colour"
    }
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "On Task Teacher Recommended",
      "data": [
        null,
        null,
        10688,
        null,
        4624,
        4330,
        null,
        5220,
        169,
        5220,
        4330,
        9144,
        4345
      ],
      "color": "#86E067",
      "events": {},
      "point": {
        "events": false
      },
      "customEvents": {
        "series": {},
        "point": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "On Task Student Discovered",
      "data": [
        null,
        null,
        10373,
        null,
        5384,
        5301,
        null,
        5521,
        1002,
        5599,
        5387,
        15535,
        5373
      ],
      "color": "#5CB5E5",
      "events": {},
      "point": {
        "events": false
      },
      "customEvents": {
        "series": {},
        "point": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Uncategorised",
      "data": [
        null,
        null,
        341,
        null,
        226,
        226,
        null,
        226,
        425,
        2240,
        1281,
        3727,
        1334
      ],
      "color": "#F98157",
      "events": {},
      "point": {
        "events": false
      },
      "customEvents": {
        "series": {},
        "point": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Off Task",
      "data": [
        null,
        null,
        -18937,
        null,
        -7056,
        -7034,
        null,
        -7163,
        -1271,
        -7208,
        -7091,
        -21658,
        -7050
      ],
      "color": "#E3454D",
      "events": {},
      "point": {
        "events": false
      },
      "customEvents": {
        "series": {},
        "point": {}
      }
    }
  ]
}
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [scrollbars-for-any-axis](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/224-scrollbars-for-any-axis/) to add scroll in highcharts like highstock. you have to use highstock js instead of highcharts js.

You have to use `max` attribute to set number of column you want to see in x-axis.

```js
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "chart": {
    "type": "column"
  },
  "title": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": [
      "Start Term 1",
      "Start Term 2",
      "29-Sep",
      "Start Term 3",
      "03-Oct",
      "05-Oct",
      "Start Term 4",
      "12-Oct",
      "20-Oct",
      "23-Oct",
      "30-Oct",
      "17-Nov",
      "21-Nov"
    ],
    "labels": {
      "style": {
        "font-size": "12px"
      },
      "useHTML": true
    },
    min: 0,  
    max: 4,  //this is value to be changed based on column number 
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: true
    },
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Time (hh:mm)"
    },
    "tickInterval": 600,
    "labels": {},
    "gridLineWidth": 0,
    "plotLines": [{
      "value": 0,
      "width": 1,
      "color": "#000",
      "zIndex": 4
    }],
    "tickmarkPlacement": "on",

  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "column": {
      "stacking": "normal",
      "events": {}
    }
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "shared": true,
    "crosshairs": true
  },
  "legend": {
    "align": "right",
    "verticalAlign": "top",
    "itemStyle": {
      "display": "none"
    },
    "title": {
      "text": "Click a colour"
    }
  },
  "series": [{
    "name": "On Task Teacher Recommended",
    "data": [
      null,
      null,
      10688,
      null,
      4624,
      4330,
      null,
      5220,
      169,
      5220,
      4330,
      9144,
      4345
    ],
    "color": "#86E067",
    "events": {},
    "point": {
      "events": false
    },
    "customEvents": {
      "series": {},
      "point": {}
    }
  }, {
    "name": "On Task Student Discovered",
    "data": [
      null,
      null,
      10373,
      null,
      5384,
      5301,
      null,
      5521,
      1002,
      5599,
      5387,
      15535,
      5373
    ],
    "color": "#5CB5E5",
    "events": {},
    "point": {
      "events": false
    },
    "customEvents": {
      "series": {},
      "point": {}
    }
  }, {
    "name": "Uncategorised",
    "data": [
      null,
      null,
      341,
      null,
      226,
      226,
      null,
      226,
      425,
      2240,
      1281,
      3727,
      1334
    ],
    "color": "#F98157",
    "events": {},
    "point": {
      "events": false
    },
    "customEvents": {
      "series": {},
      "point": {}
    }
  }, {
    "name": "Off Task",
    "data": [
      null,
      null, -18937,
      null, -7056, -7034,
      null, -7163, -1271, -7208, -7091, -21658, -7050
    ],
    "color": "#E3454D",
    "events": {},
    "point": {
      "events": false
    },
    "customEvents": {
      "series": {},
      "point": {}
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<!--<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knmeg73e/) demo

OR

You can use [chart.zoomType](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.zoomType) to zoom chart.

```js
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', 
    {
  "chart": {
    "type": "column",
    zoomType:'x' //only x axis zoom
  },
  "title": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": [
      "Start Term 1",
      "Start Term 2",
      "29-Sep",
      "Start Term 3",
      "03-Oct",
      "05-Oct",
      "Start Term 4",
      "12-Oct",
      "20-Oct",
      "23-Oct",
      "30-Oct",
      "17-Nov",
      "21-Nov"
    ],
    "labels": {
      "style": {
        "font-size": "12px"
      },
      "useHTML": true
    }
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Time (hh:mm)"
    },
    "tickInterval": 600,
    "labels": {},
    "gridLineWidth": 0,
    "plotLines": [
      {
        "value": 0,
        "width": 1,
        "color": "#000",
        "zIndex": 4
      }
    ],
    "tickmarkPlacement": "on"
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "column": {
      "stacking": "normal",
      "events": {}
    }
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "shared": true,
    "crosshairs": true
  },
  "legend": {
    "align": "right",
    "verticalAlign": "top",
    "itemStyle": {
      "display": "none"
    },
    "title": {
      "text": "Click a colour"
    }
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "On Task Teacher Recommended",
      "data": [
        null,
        null,
        10688,
        null,
        4624,
        4330,
        null,
        5220,
        169,
        5220,
        4330,
        9144,
        4345
      ],
      "color": "#86E067",
      "events": {},
      "point": {
        "events": false
      },
      "customEvents": {
        "series": {},
        "point": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "On Task Student Discovered",
      "data": [
        null,
        null,
        10373,
        null,
        5384,
        5301,
        null,
        5521,
        1002,
        5599,
        5387,
        15535,
        5373
      ],
      "color": "#5CB5E5",
      "events": {},
      "point": {
        "events": false
      },
      "customEvents": {
        "series": {},
        "point": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Uncategorised",
      "data": [
        null,
        null,
        341,
        null,
        226,
        226,
        null,
        226,
        425,
        2240,
        1281,
        3727,
        1334
      ],
      "color": "#F98157",
      "events": {},
      "point": {
        "events": false
      },
      "customEvents": {
        "series": {},
        "point": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Off Task",
      "data": [
        null,
        null,
        -18937,
        null,
        -7056,
        -7034,
        null,
        -7163,
        -1271,
        -7208,
        -7091,
        -21658,
        -7050
      ],
      "color": "#E3454D",
      "events": {},
      "point": {
        "events": false
      },
      "customEvents": {
        "series": {},
        "point": {}
      }
    }
  ]
}
);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7kfr5jf/) demo